# find maximum count in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing a sample data of covid variant cases

```
country      covid_variant       cases
 USA           SARS Covid        2000
 USA           Delta             100
 USA           Omicron           500
 Mexico        SARS Covid        2000
 USA           Omicron           400
```

How can I get the data based on max cases of each variant?

```
covid_variant   countries   max_cases
 SARS Covid      USA           2000
 SARS Covid      Mexico        2000
 Delta           USA           100
 Omicron         USA           500
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY covid_variant, country
                                 ORDER BY cases DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT covid_variant, country, cases
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I think you should take out country while partitioning.

Comment: ...The OP clearly wants to report every variant/country once, so I disagree with your comment.

Comment: True. I misunderstood. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is MSSQL, with TSQL syntax, one possible answer is:

```
select covid_variant, country, MAX(cases) as max_cases
from [tablename] 
group by covid_variant, country
order by covid_variant, country
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using MySQL 5.7 try using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT covid_variant, 
       country, 
       MAX(cases) AS max_cases 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY covid_variant, country 
ORDER BY max_cases DESC, country DESC;
```

**RESULT**

```
covid_variant  country  max_cases  
-------------  -------  -----------
SARS Covid     USA             2000
SARS Covid     Mexico          2000
Omicron        USA              500
Delta          USA              100
```